# Footnote near author's name does not appear

Tags: footnotes, journal-publishing

I'm submitting a paper at AISTATS 2015, and I wish to add a footnote about an author. I tried using `\thanks` and `\footnote`, but only the footnote number appears, the footnote text does not appear.

Here's the style file we are required to use: https://github.com/vitorguizilini/AISTATS2015/blob/master/aistats2015.sty and a sample paper: http://pastebin.com/sXzTDvLU (see line 33 for the footnote).

My ultimate aim is to achieve something like this: http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/proceedings/papers/v5/sunehag09a/sunehag09a.pdf

I'm not familiar with LaTeX programming. Any idea how the style file should be modified?

Thanks!

Comment: you may have to use the separate elements: `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext{...}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a `\footnote` on any element in a "closed" environment (titles, authors, captions, ...) will be absent from the output, so a different approach must
be taken.

instead of `\footnote`, enter `\footnotemark` with the author:

```
\author{name of author\footnotemark}
```

then, after the "closed" environment is complete (here probably ended
by `\maketitle`), enter the footnote material itself:

```
\footnotetext{text of footnote}
```

if there is more than one footnote involved (say, separately for two
authors), it will be necessary to adjust the counter before issuing the
first `\footnotetext`.  this would be done by

```
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
```

or other appropriate value.